# Is It possible to skipping componentDIdMount Lifecycle method in react?

Tags: reactjs

Here , I want to restrict my component to render componentDidMount Life cycle method.How can I make it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by render componentDidMount lifecycle method? componentDidMount is called after first render. can you explain more what exactly you want to do with example?

Comment: @eramit2010 

I have created my project using SSR. There is API call happens when SSR renders HTML page on server side. but after rendering it I have also call same API in componentDidMount lifecycle in respective component.So Problem here is,There are two API calls happens for same page on rendering..one is from SSR and one is from componentDIdMount..So I would like to prevent calling componentDidMount to reduce api call....

Comment: componentDidMount doesn't get called with SSR as per react docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: @eramit2010 It is not called with SSR.. It is call after SSR renders.

Comment: I guess your component is mounting twice, that is reason your componentDidMount is called twice.

Comment: @eramit2010 That's I need to stop calling componentDidMount lifecycle..Is there any way or do you have other solution for this problem?

Comment: you need to find why your component is mounting 2 times, or if you are using redux as store management you can store some state which says first mount is done so don't call api if that state is true.

Answer (score 0):

You never render `componentDidMount`, only functions written inside it is executed when any component is mounted in the stack, so if you dont write anything inside it, even if its executed nothing will happen . Only `render()` function is responsible to render the contents on the mobile screen.

SO `componentDidMount` is optional if you are using a class based approach.But componentDidMount is ideal to execute the API calls if you have some, since componentDidMount is executed at first.